# How to paginate with return as json laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-pagination

I want to create a pagination with return as json, but I'm getting an error like below

> ErrorException in Macroable.php line 74:
>   Method links does not exist.

here my controller code

```
 public function getcustomer($id){

    $customer = Customer::find($id)->paginate(5);

    return response()->json([$customer], 200);
}
```

and here my blade code

```
{{$customer->links('vendor.pagination.pagination')}}
```

how can I create a pagination with json response() ?

Comment: You could also use this api. It is quite easy to integrate this and works well along with following all the JSON API specs. https://github.com/spatie/laravel-json-api-paginate

Comment: hi @DhavalChheda, thanks for your suggestion :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The Laravel paginator result classes implement the `Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Jsonable` Interface contract and expose the `toJson` method, so it's very easy to convert your pagination results to JSON.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/pagination#converting-results-to-json

If you want to build links, you should do it manually. Or you should return pagination as usual and use `render()` method to build links and create copy of pagination object to convert it to JSON with `toJson()`.